# DHCP Client Can't Find DHCP Server

Tags: windows, linux, dhcp, iptables

I currently have 3 machines:

1. CentOS (router)
   eth1 - 18.0.168.1
   eth2 - 145.165.34.1
2. Windows Server 2008 (server)
   18.0.168.2

DHCP scope - 145.165.34.10 - 145.165.34.20

3. Windows 7 (client)

   - Supposed to use DHCP

I can't get my Windows 7 client to get an address from the Windows Server 2008 DHCP server.

Every network interface can ping each other (ex. 18.0.168.2 can ping 18.0.168.1 & 145.165.34.1 and the other way around).

My Linux machine acting as the router has default IP tables. Other than this command which may or may not be right:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp -d 18.0.168.2 --dport 67:68 -j ACCEPT
```

I have also tried it after I flushed the IP tables.

I was looking at the dhcrelay command but it seems CentOS doesn't have it and I am not even sure how to use it.

Comment: If you `tcpdump` the traffic on the router, are you seeing the DHCP request packets from the client?

Comment: Is the W7 box on the eth1 or eth2 interface?

Comment: Aside: Are you really routing between MIT and Utrecht? If not, then you probably want to know about (and use) RFC 1918 private addresses, rather than misusing real public addresses. Otherwise someday you'll wonder why a site at MIT (or Utrecht) isn't loading.

Comment: I agree with @Spiff :D

Comment: First thing that stood out to me as well was your choice of IP Address space. You should only use internal IP space (RFC 1918) for your internal IPs.